# Invariance Property of Vowpal Wabbit Updates - Explaination

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

One of the discussed nice aspects of the procedure that Vowpal Wabbit uses for updates to sgd 
[pdf](http://lowrank.net/nikos/pubs/liw.pdf) is so-called weight invariance, described in the linked as:

"Among these updates we mainly focus on a novel
set of updates that satisfies an additional invariance
property: for all importance weights of h, the update
is equivalent to two updates with importance weight
h/2. We call these updates importance invariant."

What does this mean and why is it useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often different data samples have different weighting ( eg the costs of misclassification error  for one group of data  is higher than for other classes).
Most error metrics are of the form $\sum_i e_i$ where e_i is the loss ( eg squared error) on data point $i$. Therefore weightings of the form $\sum_i w_i e_i$ are equivalent to duplicating the data w_i times (eg for w_i integer).

One simple case is if you have repeated data - rather than keeping all the duplicated data points, you just "weight" your one repeated sample by the number of instances.

Now whilst this is easy to do in a batch setting, it is hard in vowpal wabbits online big data setting: given that you have a large data set, you do not just want to represent the data n times to deal with the weighting ( because it increases your computational load). Similarly, just multiplying the gradient vector by the weighting - which is correct in batch gradient descent - will cause big problems for stochastic/online gradient descent: essentially you shoot off in one direction ( think of large integer weights) then you shoot off in the other - causing significant instability. SGD essentially relies on all the errors to be of roughly the same order ( so that the learning rate can be set appropriately). So what they propose is to ensure that the update for training sample x_i with weight n is equivalent to presenting training sample x_i n times consecutively.

The idea being that presenting it consecutively reduces the problem because the error gradient (for that single example $x_i$) reduces for each consecutive presentation and update (as you get closer & closer to the minimum for that specific example). In other words the consecutive updates provides a kind of feedback control.

To me it sounds like you would still have instabilities (you get to zero error on x_i, then you get to zero error on x_i+1,...). the learning rate will need to be adjusted to take into account the size of the weights.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I am still a tad confused: 1) About consecutive updates - why is this better than seeing the same observation the same number of times, but out of order? and 2) I dont get the phrase used regarding "for all importance weights of h, the update is equivalent to two updates with importance weight h=2". It seems like what is important is that the process is equivalent to h updates with weight =1.

Comment: consecutive updates- its not that its better ( it isn't), but that it doesn't fit in the online "memory-less" setting of vowpal-wabbit ( in order to reorder the data you need to store the data). second is a typo? In the abstract it says:  "that updating twice with importance
weight h is equivalent to updating once with
importance weight 2h"

Comment: Sorry, I read your response: "The idea being that presenting it consecutively reduces the problem because the error gradient... " as saying that if you were relying on adding a record with weight n, n times (with weight 1), ignoring the computational burden, it was better to present the record to the algorithm n-times consecutively. So, this was the "goal" VW is trying to achieve, but with something equivalent that only requires a record to be present 1 times in the data.

Comment: Regarding the typo, YES, seems I should have typed "...h/2". I changed the question. This is stated in this fashion the way you added in the comment and as the question now states, later in the paper. Even with this new wording, I fail to see what the point it...likely obvious, I am just not latching onto it yet.

Comment: So which bit? a) can't present the data out of order in online setting ( and computational load). b) why n consecutive updates is better than 1 single update of weight n: gradient descent - "overshoot", c) why their proposed single update is better than n consecutive updates - computational load d) why importance weights are useful in a statistical learning system

Comment: I think I understand b) in that a huge weight multiplied against the gradient will really cause a large update and it will act as an outlier for tuning a learning rate. I think I understand c) in that having to repeat the update for a single observation with weight n, n-times will of course cause more computations. I know d) well - at least in the case of batch learning, where it is for example useful for unbalanced classes. I don't know of an example in true online learning (my VW experience is with a fixed offline data set that is fed into VW because it doesn't all fit in memory).

Comment: So, my confusion is for a) as well as the initial question about the invariance property - what it means and why it matters.

Comment: Does invariance here simply mean that a single update (as they propose) achieves the same thing as seeing the record multiple times? Is that all it is saying?

Comment: a) VW basically streams the data- so how do you present the samples out of order, that requires you to store the data. And yes - thats all they mean by invariance.

Comment: a) I thought that was what you were saying - that if you were presenting an observation multiple times (ignoring the computational cost) it was better that it be consecutive, as that would result in less instability of a large weight!

Comment: Oh geez if that is all it means, then that was pretty straightforward - I guess my typo did not help matters for my confusion :) thanks!

Comment: Sean, silly, but can I confirm with you, this whole idea is really about making importance weights (as shown in the input format required by VW) work (and not overshoot)?

Comment: yes that's right